# Why is my Android application slow?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I am developing now using ViewPager and RecyclerView in "Samsung Galaxy Note 3".
All Fragments have RecyclerView, and ViewHolder uses ImageView, TextView and ProgressBar.
Currently there are about 7 RecyclerViews per Fragment on average, and each RecyclerView has about 20 on average ViewHolder.
But the problem is that the application loading speed is too slow.
I think there are times when this problem is heard when there are too many RecyclerViews. Is my guess correct?

If so, how much RecyclerView should be per Fragment?

Comment: use 2 recyclerview per fragment. and do not load all fragments at once

Comment: can you put across the UI here so i can suggest the possible approach

Comment: it depends on how much recyclerview are loading at same time. you are using viewpager with some fragments. if fragments contain 7 recyclerview then 5 fragments * 7recyclerview=35 load at same time which cause rendering issues and skip frames

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sometime it happens due to the size of images you are loading..try to resize your images before loading into view pager or recyclerView

Comment: I am also using "Glide" image loading library now. Even if you use that library, can you have the problem you mentioned?

Comment: i am using Picasso ,and resizing the image before loading into image view.

Comment: Glide and Picasso do essentially the same thing